# print random number into iframe atrribute name

Tags: javascript, iframe, random, numbers, src

I have the following script that creates and random number and writes it.

My Javascript for the random number is:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000001);
if (number % 100 == 0) {} {
// Print the number
document.write(number);
}
```

I have several iframes and they all need random numbers. How do i get this to print a different number inside the iframe src attribute as shown below?

```
<iframe src="www.website.com?rng=[RANDOMNUMBER]"></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Does it really have to be a 'random' number?  Why not just use something as simple as this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){    
     document.write("<iframe src='www.website.com?rng=" + i + "'></iframe>");
}
```